# JS. Как удалить элемент из LocalStorage в приложении ToDo

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>MyToDoApp</title>
      <script defer src="./main.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="small-cont">
        <h1>My To-do's</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

1. Элемент списка

   ```
   //Создаю элементы
   var form = document.createElement('form');
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   var ul = document.createElement('ul');
   ul.classList.add('list-group');
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   var btnGroup = document.createElement('div');
   var delBtn = document.createElement('button');
   //Обращаюсь к хранилищу
   let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : []
   localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
   const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
   //Создание поля ввода
   function createElements() {
     let smallCont = document.querySelector('.small-cont');
     form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
     input.classList.add('form-control');
     input.placeholder = ('Введите название нового дела');
     smallCont.append(form);
     form.append(input);
     smallCont.append(ul);
   }
   createElements();
   //Создание отдельного пункта списка с кнопкой "Удалить", которая не работает!!!!!!!
   function createLi(text) {
     let li = document.createElement('li');
     let btnGroup = document.createElement('div');
     const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
     li.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
     delBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
     delBtn.style.cssText = 'z-index: 5;';
     btnGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm')
     delBtn.textContent = 'Удалить';
     li.textContent = text;
     btnGroup.append(delBtn);
     li.append(btnGroup);
     ul.appendChild(li);

     delBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
       if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
         this.closest('li').remove();
       }
     })
   }

   //Слушаю поле ввода
   form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (!input.value) {
       return
     };
   //Добавляю полученное задание в хранилище
     itemsArray.push(input.value)
     localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
     createLi(input.value);
     input.value = '';
   })
   data.forEach(item => {
     createLi(item)
   })
   ```

Comment: `localStorage.remove();` - это что?

Comment: Спасибо. Да тупанул, removeItem. Но все равно не работает, кроме clear().

Answer (score 0):

> Слушаю кнопку "УДАЛИТЬ", но этого не получается

Да, просто этот элемент ещё не создан. Попробуйте поместить этот код в функцию, которая создаёт элемент

> ```
>   this.remove();
> ```

вот тут вы ведь хотите удалить li, а по факту удалите кнопку. Нужно от кнопки добраться до родителя-родителя, например, через `e.target.parentElement.parentElement`

Comment: Спасибо Большое! <li> удаляется! Я оценил ваш ответ, но так как репутация низкая, оценка не отображается публично)

Comment: Еще вопрос, по поводу удаления из хранилища, никак не получается удалить из массива.

Comment: Там под вашим вопросам, в комменте отметили в чем проблема. Посмотрите справку по удалению элемента из локалсторэдж https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Благодарю. Прочитал. Все равно не получается с  localStorage.removeItem();
Если указываю localStorage.clear(); Работает, но удаляет все из хранилища.

Comment: Ну так, не видя, что изменили трудно сказать.

Comment: сохранил новый код, надеюсь сможете помочь. removeItem не помогает)) по крайней мере мне. Написан такую функцию в конце кода, тоже фейл.

Comment: function delItem(index) {

Comment: let itemsArray = JSON.getItem(localStorage.getItem('items'))

Comment: data.splice(item, 1)

Comment: localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data))                                                                
  delItem();
}